# Formation and solving procedure (Optimization)

Tags: probability, optimization, operations-research

There are $n_1, n_2, n_3, ..., n_n $companies are there.

Say total number of companies in a region is $'n'$ , where $'n'$ is some positive integer.

The average no. of employees working in each company is $'k'. $

For example,

the no. of employees working in first company $n_1$ is $4$ (say) and in $n_2$ is $3$ (say), ..., $n_n$ is $48$ (say)

$Note:$

1) $4, 3, ..., 48$ are all obviously positive integers. Thus, the average no. of employees in all companies are $'k'$ (say), also positive integer.

2) The least number of employees in any company is $3$ and maximum no of employees is $2000$

$Restriction:$ Every employee has to work 7 days in other company or companies in year is mandatory.

For example, $k_1$ is one of the employee in company $n_{13}$

Then, $k_1$ has to work $7$ days in others company (other than his parent company $n_{13}$).

$Note:$

This $k_1$ can work  $2 $days in company $n_1$; $1$ day in $n_{12}$ and $3$ days in $n_{100}$ and $1$ day in $n_{23}$.

This means, $k_1$ can work in single slot of consecutive of $7$ days in any company other than his parent company or he can work in different days ( all together $7$ days) in a year.

**Now the question is: "How to formulate the entire problem, by keeping the following in mind"**

1. All employees has to work in other companies either consecutive of $7$ days or different days in different companies all together $7$ days in year other than his/her parent company.
2. One or more employee of one company can opt work in other companies in single or different slots are allowed.
   For example: $n_2$ has $3$ employees. all three or any one can opt work in other than company $n_2.$
3. least no of employees are $3$ and maximum employees are $2000.$
4. All companies and all employees are in consideration of the cited above restrictions.

**With respect to the above information, without leaving one employee and without leaving one company, how best we can formulate? and how many combinations we can create?**

I hope the edited post will give some clarity. Kindly help in formulating the problem and solving in general.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why use $n$ for both the index limit and the variable itself? >:(

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee! still .. I am not able to get you. Can you help me in detail?